# getting error _LoginPage.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, cypress

this is my code

```js
/// \<reference types = "cypress" /\>

class LoginPage
{

    visit()
    {
        cy.visit("https://ec2-35-179-99-242.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2021/")
    
    }
    
    username(name)
    {
        const field = cy.get('[id=UserName]')
        field.clear()
        field.type(name)
        return this
    }
    
    Password(pwd)
    {
        const pass = cy.get('[id=Password]')
        pass.clear()
        pass.type(pwd)
        return this
    }
    
    Submit()
    {
       const button = cy.get('[type=submit]')
       button.click()
    }

}

export default LoginPage
```

```js
/// \<reference types = "cypress" /\>

import LoginPage from './PageObject/LoginPage'

    it('valid test', function()
    {
    
        const Login = new LoginPage()
         Login.visit()
         Login.username('arslan')
         Login.Password('123')
         Login.Submit()
        
    
    })
```

i make object of Login class

```js
const Login = new LoginPage()
```

but getting error
getting error _LoginPage.default is not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

Try using a named export

```js
export class LoginPage {

  visit() {
    cy.visit("https://ec2-35-179-99-242.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2021/")
  }
  ...
}
```

and import like this

```js
import { LoginPage } from './PageObject/LoginPage'
```

Comment: tried but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `function` reserved name before all your functions names or declare  the functions like a const using an arrow function like:

```
function visit()
    {
        cy.visit("https://ec2-35-179-99-242.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2021/")
    
    }
```

or

```
const visit = () =>
    {
        cy.visit("https://ec2-35-179-99-242.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2021/")
    
    }
```